# Taking input using fscanf in C

Tags: c, debugging, file-io, structure

I am trying to write a program in c which takes in a list of blood donors as input and stores it in a pointer variable **donor**

Here is an example of a list containing data of 5 individuals(name,gender,age and bloodgroup) :

> Ranganath M 22 A-
>   Shachi F 27 B+
>   Lakshmi F 40 O-
>   Sriram M 19 B+
>   Sanandan M 35 AB+
>   (*take note of the spaces in between*)

Here is a part of the C code that takes the input from a file called **donorslist.txt**

```
struct Bloodbank
{
        char name[20];
        char gender;
        int age;
        char bloodgrp[3];
}
receiver;
int main (int argc, char *argv[])         // taking input from the command line           
{
      if(argc!=5)
       exit(1);
  int found =0;
        strcpy(receiver.name,argv[1]);
        receiver.gender=*argv[2];
        receiver.age = atoi(*argv[3]);
        strcpy(receiver.bloodgrp,argv[4]);

        struct Bloodbank *donor = (struct Bloodbank *)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(struct Bloodbank));
        FILE  *fp;
        fp = fopen("donorslist.txt", "r");
        for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)                     // SIZE has been defined =5
        {
                fscanf(fp,"%s[^ ]",donor[i].name);
                fgetc(fp);                         // to skip the whitespace 
                fscanf(fp,"%c" ,&donor[i].gender);
                fgetc(fp);
                fscanf(fp,"%d" ,&donor[i].age);
                fgetc(fp);
                fscanf(fp,"%s[^\n]",donor[i].bloodgrp);
                fgetc(fp);                              //to skip the newline 
        }
```

Here i give the input from the command line as :
`./a.out John M 30 B+`

And it throws a **Segmentation fault(core dumped)**

It seems that there is some error in the way i have used and declared the structure pointer ,but i can't seem to figure out how .
I want to know how the memory  allocated for a structure pointer is different from a generic pointer like **int *** and the error in my code.

Thanks

Comment: `atoi(*argv[3])` should be giving you a compile-time warning that you need to fix also. Also, `AB+` needs four characters to store as a string.

Comment: why not read all the  fields in one fscanf ?

Comment: @Ken Y-N i have edited the code and the same error

Comment: @Starboy check also Ken's suggestion about blood group length. You probably don't know that strings always need an extra char for the string terminator

Comment: @Cubo78 It was a mistake , but still it shows the segmentation fault.

Comment: `%s[^ ]` is pretty strange. Did you mean `%s` or `%[^ ]`? In the second case, it will stop at a space just like `%s` does. Also `%s[^\n]` they are hybrid, neither one thing or another. I also recommend a space before `%c` so `fscanf(fp," %c" ,&donor[i].gender);` This filters the space remaining in the buffer. Aside: what will you do with a name like "Da Silva"?

Comment: You haven't checked `argc` to find out if the arguments were provided. One frequent segfault I get, is forgetting that and forgetting the arguments too. Please *always* check `argc`. Without that, there is no point looking for a segfault elsewhere, because I won't believe you remember to provide arguments.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have checked it . That part is fine

Comment: No, the code does not contain `if(argc < 5) exit(1);` It is not fine. But if it does, then you haven't posted your *actual code*.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry for the carelessness . I have updated the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203738/discussion-between-starboy-and-weather-vane).

Answer (score 1):

1. When you reserve memory for a c string you must take the **null terminator into account**:

   ```
   struct Bloodbank
   {
     char name[ 20 + 1 ];
     char gender;
     int age;
     char bloodgrp[ 3 + 1 ];
   } receiver;
   ```
2. `atoi` requires a string as an input. `*argv[ 3 ]` is the **first character** of the third argument, not the argument. To get the actual argument, remove `*`:

   ```
   receiver.age = atoi( argv[ 3 ] );
   ```
3. You do not check the file was **successfully opened**:

   ```
   if ( !fp )
   {
     printf( "could not open file" );
     return -1;
   }
   ```